# How can I use interpolated strings as keys in a Javascript associative array?

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I'm maintaining a bit of Javascript code that uses an associative array to store progress messages, something like this:

```
const encouragingMessages = {
   100: "You've done 100! Well done!",
   200: "You're half-way there! Good job!",
   300: "Three-quarters done! Nearly finished!"
};
```

I know that keys are strings, not integers, but my issue is that I want those numbers to be controllable depending on the total, something more like this:

```
const encouragingMessages = {
   `${parseInt(total / 4)}`: `You've done ${parseInt(total / 4)}! Well done!`,
   `${parseInt(total / 2)}`: "You're half-way there! Good job!",
   `${parseInt(total * .75)}`: "Three-quarters done! Nearly finished!"
};
```

But although using raw integers works ok, trying to use an interpolated string doesn't work, even when including letters, and using `toString()`:

```
    `foo${parseInt(100).toString()}`: 'bar',
```

Results in `Parsing error: Unexpected token`.

Aren't these strings still strings, and usable as keys? I know that using raw integers themselves is probably bad practice, but my understanding is that these keys are strings:

```
> typeof `foo${parseInt(100)}`;
'string'
```

and would (I thought) therefore be usable as keys in this situation.

I'll probably just change this altogether to something clearer, but for my own understanding & to avoid wasting time in future I'd appreciate any clarification on why this doesn't work.

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate topics offer a solution and an explanation. However, I would recommend a different approach: instead of making the property names dynamic, just divide by `total` when *accessing* the map.

Comment: Oops sorry posting a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's JS syntax. If you want to use a string or any variable value as a key you need to use computed properties. Just wrap your key in [ ] braces. An example would be  ["my crazy string key"]: "my value"

Comment: No damage done, and I guess they're not easy to find :-)

Comment: You'd say that in php, associative array but in JavaScript it's an object.
```
const encouragingMessages = {
  100: "You've done 100! Well done!",
  200: "You're half-way there! Good job!",
  300: "Three-quarters done! Nearly finished!"
};
let x = 200;
```
//let's suppose the number is 200 so it's only
```
encouragingMessages[`${x}`]
//"You're half-way there! Good job!"
```